# DC and crossfilter with large datasets

Tags: javascript, dataset, dc.js, crossfilter

I have been working on dc and crossfilter js and I currently have a large dataset with 550,000 rows and size 60mb csv and am facing a lot of issues with it like browser crashes etc

So , I'm trying to understand how dc and crossfilter deals with large datasets.
http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/

The example on their main site runs very smoothly and after seeing timelines->memory (in console) it goes to a max of 34 mb and slowly reduces with time

My project is taking up memory in the range of 300-500mb per dropdown selection, when it loads a json file and renders the entire visualization

So, 2 questions

- What is the backend for the dc site example? Is it possible to find out the exact backend file?
- How can I reduce the data overload on my RAM from my application, which is running very slowly and eventually crashing?

Comment: Can you share an example? You're talking about a fairly large amount of data, but it's not necessarily out of the scope of what is manageable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you can try running loading the data, and filtering it on the server. I faced a similar problem when the size of my dataset was being too big for the browser to handle. 
I posted a question a few weeks back as to implementing the same. [Using dc.js on the clientside with crossfilter on the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24184986/using-dc-js-on-the-clientside-with-crossfilter-on-the-server/)

Here is an overview of going about it.

On the client side, you'd want to create fake dimensions and fake groups that have basic functionality that dc.js expects(https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#filter-the-data-before-its-charted). You create your dc.js charts on the client side and plug in the fake dimensions and groups wherever required.

Now on the server side you have crossfilter running(https://www.npmjs.org/package/crossfilter). You create your actual dimensions and groups here.

The fakedimensions have a `.filter()` function that basically sends an ajax request to the server to perform the actual filtering. The filtering information could be encoded in the form of a query string. You'd also need a `.all()` function on your fake group to return the results of the filtering.

Comment: Thank you for this idea, can you please share an example how to go about implementing this? I have been reading it for a while but could not comprehend completely.

Comment: Can you please share an example?

Comment: Yes please give me a day.

Comment: @lastlegion Thanks a ton!! That would be super awesome. I am running the crossfilter on my server. Cant seem to figure out how to connect it to the graphs though

Comment: This is a WIP version of the demo shown in dc.js homepage. It uses crossfilter on the server: https://github.com/lastlegion/dc.js-server-side-crossfilter