# DC & crossfilter zoomable feasibility

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

Here is an example of my visualization : [image: Tab1]

Now I have been facing issues with dc & crossfilter with large datasets
Discussion : 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dc-js-user-group/fkRoFHuqg4k

[DC and crossfilter with large datasets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24435439/dc-and-crossfilter-with-large-datasets)

So, now I have decided to use aggregation meaning, I will show only daily data which will be of smaller size and can be shown easily on the tab as seen in the photo and all bar graphs are dynamically connected.

Now, when a user selects only 1 date, I want it to show hourly data for that specific day.
And, these hours can be selected by the user as per their requirement.

Do I have to put 2 bar charts for it to show daily and then hourly bars?
Or, is it possible to do it in 1 chart only?

I wanted more ideas on how to approach this problem.
All suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a context + brush approach?
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367

One chart gives the context of the entire dataset. When a subset of that chart is selected the other chart will "zoom" in to that timeframe.

In your case, you could have your server group your data by hour since that seems like your smallest aggregation.  Crossfilter could then hopefully handle the other aggregations client side.