# dc Charts not interacting with each other (with crossfilter on server side)

Tags: javascript, ajax, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm pretty new to crossfilter and dc, currently trying to build interactive dashboard with them. The data I have would easily go up to around 200MB and my browser would just crash when I do the crossfilter on the client side, so after some search online I decided to run crossfilter on the server and dc for charting on client side, and I'm following the work here [dc.js-server-side-crossfilter](https://github.com/lastlegion/dc.js-server-side-crossfilter) However, the dc charts are not interacting with each other.

So from what I understand the basic components are, server-side app.js handles Ajax calls sent from the client-side app.js, and perform required filtering then send the dimension and groups in JSON format back to the client-side, then we will create *fake* dimensions and groups and feed them into dc chart, then each user clicks/drag on the chart will then again create another Ajax call, the whole process repeats again.

Here I post the important parts in somewhat pseudo-code as the original is messy to look at,

Server-side app.js

```
var app = express();

// define variables that will get passed
var dimensions = {};
var groups     = {};

// handle the ajax call coming from client-side
app.get("/refresh", function(req, res, next){
    var results = {};
    filter = req.query["filter"] ? JSON.parse(req.query["filter"]) : {} 
    for(group_i in groups){
        var group = groups[group_i];
        if(filter[group_i]){
            dimensions[group_i].filter(filter[group_i]);
        }
        results[group_i]= {values:group.all(), 
                           top: group.top(1)[0].value,
                          };
    }
    // send result back in JSON
    res.writeHead(200, { 'content-type': 'application/json' });
    res.end((JSON.stringify(results)));
});

load data into memory {
    // do crossfiltering
    var cf = crossfilter(data);

    // dimensions
    var dateDim = cf.dimension(function(d) {return d['timestamp'];});
    var typeDim = cf.dimension(function(d) {return d['destination_type'];});

    // groups    
    var numByDate = dateDim.group();
    var numByType = typeDim.group();   

    // put these dimensions and groups into corresponding variables
    dimensions.dateDim = dateDim;
    dimensions.typeDim = typeDim;

    groups.numByDate = numByDate; 
    groups.numByType = numByType; 
}
```

Client side app.js

```
var timeChart = dc.barChart("#pvs-time-chart");

var filteredData = {};
var queryFilter = {};

var refresh = function(queryFilter){
    // make ajax call
    d3.json("/refresh?filter="+JSON.stringify(queryFilter), function(d){
        filteredData = d;
        dc.redrawAll();
    });
}

var fakeDateDim = {
    filter: function(f){
        if(f){
            queryFilter["dateDim"]=f;
            refresh(queryFilter);
        }
    },
    filterAll: function(){

    }
};

var fakeNumByDate = {
    all: function(){
        try{
            var dateFormat = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d");
            filteredData["numByDate"].values.forEach(function (d) {
                d['key'] = dateFormat.parse(d['key']);
            });
        }
        catch(err) {
            // console.log(err);
        }
        return filteredData["numByDate"].values;
    },

    order: function(){

    },

    top: function(){

    }
 };


// Make charts
timeChart
  .width(1200)
  .height(250)
  .margins({top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 50})
  .dimension(fakeDateDim)
  .group(fakeNumByDate)
  .transitionDuration(500)
  .x(d3.time.scale().domain([minDate, maxDate]))
  .elasticY(true)
  .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
  .yAxis().ticks(4);

timeChart
  .filterHandler(function(dimension, filters){
    if (filters) {
      dimension.filter(filters);
    }
    else {
      dimension.filter(null);
    };
   return filters; 
   });

// Similarly for typeChart
var typeChart = dc.rowChart("#dest-type-row-chart");
...


function init(){
    d3.json("/refresh?filter={}", function(err, d){
        filteredData = d;
        dc.renderAll();
    });
}

init();
```

I'm really stuck with why these two charts are not interacting with each other, any suggestions? (My apologies if they are obvious things)

**Edit**:

The data is loaded from a mongodb database.

The two plots are all shown correctly, so I don't think there is issue with the data itself and how they are grouped.

There are no errors being thrown. Server side debug shows (with each user click/drag):

```
GET /refresh?filter={%22dateDim%22:[[%222017-08-13T21:10:30.937Z%22,%222017-
09-08T16:02:52.755Z%22]],%22typeDim%22:
[%22Player%22,%22Schedule%22,%22Other%22,%22Game%20Stats%22]} 200 8.333 ms - 
-
```

client side has no error shown.

The issue is, when you create two dc charts on selected dimensions and groups, they are supposed to interact/change according to the user action on either one of the two charts, but the way it's set up now, user action (clicks/drag) on either of the chart does not trigger the change to the other chart at all, the bar chart can still be clicked but nothing changes.

Related links I have also checked out:

[BIG DATA VISUALIZATIONS USING CROSSFILTER AND DC.JS](http://ganeshiyer.net/blog/2014/07/19/big-data-visualization-using-crossfilter-and-dc-js/)

[Using dc.js on the clientside with crossfilter on the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24184986/using-dc-js-on-the-clientside-with-crossfilter-on-the-server/)

Comment: other than the rather vague phrase "not interacting", you haven't told us any details of the problem you're having - e.g. exact behaviour, debugging /tracing information about any errors or incorrect data or incorrect program flow - or anything at all useful. Please edit the question with more precise information.

Comment: @ADyson My bad, just edited, hopefully it's a bit more clear now.

Comment: You're missing something to actually make the reaction happen. With crossfilter on the client side, redrawAll would do this, but an asynchronous call screws that up. There are a few ways to fix this but I prefer [commitHandler](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.baseMixin.html#commitHandler. You'd pass it a callback which  calls `refresh` and only continues once it has a response.

Comment: @Gordon I come from python background and just started using js, the asynchronous in js is still confusing to me. I don't see how the async call screws things up, inside the `refresh` function, doesn't `dc.redrawAll()` wait until the d3.json ajax call returns data, so it should get the newly updated data? 
I tried to play around with commitHandler but not sure how to have `refresh` inside a callback, is there any basic examples on how to use commitHanlders?

Comment: Huh, yes I would expect that to work - you should get one redraw immediately when applying the filter (with no effect), and then another when the ajax request returns. I've seen other people do this successfully, don't know what is going wrong here, sorry. Guess I'd log everything and make sure you are getting the correct response and that the redraw triggers `.all()`, reading the data you expect.